# Linker error using OpenCL 2.0 C++ bindings header file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, opencl

I'm getting a linker error from the OpenCL 2.0 C++ bindings header file [cl2.hpp](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/api/2.0/cl2.hpp).  All my headers files come directly from the [Khronos OpenCL registry](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/) and [I build the OpenCL.lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19405596/cannot-compile-opencl-application-using-1-2-headers-in-1-1-version/33018003#33018003) file myself.  I don't get an error using the OpenCL 1.2 C++ bindings header file.

I am using Qt 5.5.0 and Visual Studio C++ 2013 with Windows7 64-bit.

The error is related to multiply defined symbols in multiple source files.

```
mainwindow.cpp.obj:-1: error: LNK2005: "enum cl::QueueProperties __cdecl
 cl::operator|(enum cl::QueueProperties,enum cl::QueueProperties)"
 (??Ucl@@YA?AW4QueueProperties@0@W410@0@Z) already defined in main.cpp.obj
```

I don't understand why the compiler is saying this is already defined.

I have narrowed down the problem to this code in the cl2.hpp file

```
QueueProperties operator|(QueueProperties lhs, QueueProperties rhs)
{
    return static_cast<QueueProperties>(static_cast<cl_command_queue_properties>(lhs) | static_cast<cl_command_queue_properties>(rhs));
}
```

When I comment that code out my project compiles and runs fine. Do you have any clue to what this problem is? Is it a poor design in the cl2.hpp header file?

Comment: Could well be a bug in `cl2.hpp`. If you mark the offending function as `inline`, does it resolve the issue?

Comment: I do concur with @jprice , this looks like a case of missing `inline` here since if the header is included in two different compilation units, you'll have a multiple define for the function...

Comment: @jprice, yes, `inline` fixes it. Feel free to write up an answer. Is there a better solution than inline? I usually use static inline. What about an anonymous namespace? My C++ skills are weak. I guess somebody should report a bug to Khronos?

Comment: I think `inline` or `static inline` is fine, that's how many of the other functions in the header are handled, this one just slipped through the cracks. I can fix this within Khronos, so it will get pushed out with the next release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the offending function is a non-inline member function. This means that when `cl2.hpp` is included from multiple source files, there will be multiple copies of the function definition that will clash when these object files are linked together.

The simple solution is to mark the offending function as `inline` (as many of the other functions in the header already are).

Comment: I only included the cl2.hpp file once explicitly. However, I think to to Qt's moc preprocessor it's implicitly included again. I see the duplicate in a file generated by Qt with an extension `_automoc.cpp`.